# header border gets gaps on edges when I change to sticky html css

Tags: html, css

Had `position: absolute` and it worked fine, the bottom border went from left to right viewport edges. When I change to sticky there are little gaps on either side even though `width: 100%`. It also gets a gap on top. This is also happening with the footer which has the same style except border-top. How do I make it sticky and not have the gaps? Thanks

```
header{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```
<header></header>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Have you tried *{ margin:0; } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will it work.

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works!! :) but now the footer is in the middle of the screen now, do you happen to know how to fix it?

footer {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid red;
}

Comment: I put a link above. You can fix it by looking from there.

Answer (score 0):

The User-Agent StyleSheet is the default CSS that comes with every HTML page. It's the stylesheet that causes text to be serif by default and buttons to have a gray background. A lot of developers find that the UAS comes in their way when trying to style their HTML documents, so they apply CSS Resets.

CSS resets set a better default starting point so the UAS doesn't come in your way, similar to the problem that you're facing. The 23 most common resets are for margin, padding, and box-sizing.

```css
/* CSS Reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Your Header Styles*/
header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  top: 0; /* I've added this line to make your header stick to the top */
}
```

```html
<body style="height: 1000px;">
  <header>Here is a sticky header</header>
</body>
```

The `* {}` selector ensures that all elements have their padding and margin reset, along with their box-sizing.